# How can I convert markdown to PDF using CSS with a table of contents?

Tags: css, pdf, markdown, wkhtmltopdf, pandoc

I tried using the Pandoc and Wkhtmltopdf, and Wkhtmltopdf is working fine. But I am unable to get a table of contents and page numbering. Is there a way to get those using Pandoc?

Edit:

I would like to add another potential solution that has helped me. It is [PagedMeda/Paged.js](https://pagedmedia.org/pagedjs-sneak-peeks/). I allows for the usage of [PagedMedia CSS](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-page-3/), which you can use to make a table of contents.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pipe the output to `wkhtmltopdf` and use its table of contents producer (`pandoc --toc` doesn't do page numbers):

```
pandoc input.md -s -t html | wkhtmltopdf toc - output.pdf
```